# Use one button instead of two for changing string

Tags: javascript, string

I have a variable and I need it to switch its string back and fourth each time the user presses a button. I'm using two functions to do that, one to change it to 'short' and one to 'long'. The default setting on my website is 'short'. The problem is that I don't want it to use two buttons since it would take away space. I need one function that will change it from a to b and from b to a.

```
var sl = "short"; 
function short() {
sl = "short";
}
function long() {
sl = "long";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should fit what you want to do.
Its untested, but it should work.

```
var sl = "short";
var on = 1;

if (on == 1) { 
 on = 0;
 console.log("Short became long");
 sl = "long";
 }
else if (on == 0) {
 on = 1;
 console.log("Long became short");
 sl = "short";
 }
```

We have an integer variable which represents the 'default on' state (you can use a boolean instead of an integer if you want)
When the code is ran, if 'on' is **1**, then it sets it to **0** and executes the 'off' code. 
If the variable 'on' is **0**, it will set it to **1** and execute the 'on' code. You can put this inside a function and call the function
to execute on/off code.

Comment: and how do i call the function from html?

Comment: @yollen  **<button onclick="myFunction()">Sample button</button>**

Comment: @yollen Be sure to place the JS code between **<script>** / **</script>** tags.

Answer (score 1):

```
var sl = "short"; 
function change() {
    if (sl == "short"){
        sl = "long";
    }
    else{
        sl = "short";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make a function that checks what it is, then make it the opposite.

```
var sl = "short";
function change() {
   if (sl == "short") {
      sl = "long";
   } else if (sl == "long") {
      sl = "short";
   } else raise an error;
```

Comment: You are missing the semi-columns.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code:

```
var sl = 'short';
if (sl == 'short') sl = 'long';
else if (sl == 'long') sl = 'short';
```

Comment: You are missing out the brackets { } at the condition statements.

Comment: @Dragg if there is only one line of code for if statements, it does not need brackets.

Comment: They aren't needed, but are recommended if he/she wants to expand the statement.

Comment: @SatchmoSanders i want to expand it, but ty for answering